# phpmyadmin: save query history to central server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup a central phpmyadmin server for multiple DB servers.

was reading these:

- http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/pmadb
- http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=55811

Signon works fine for both localhost(phpmyadmin.example.com) and the remote server(db1.example.com) and users are able to login to both. I have created the phpmyadmin database and pma_* tables in phpmyadmin.example.com. But history gets saved for sql queries only on localhost. When user logs in to db1, he sees this error:

> The additional features for working with linked tables have been
>   deactivated.

more details:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Designer: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
Tracking: Disabled
```

The documentation says that it is possible to save history in a central server. But am I doing it right? I tried to create a another set of pma_* tables and point db1 configuration to them. Didn't help. What I feel is that this configuration is trying to save history for db1 in db1 itself and I have to create pma_* tables in db1 (which I want to avoid). How can I point all servers' history to phpmyadmin.example.com?

Here is my config.inc.php

```
$i = 0;
$i++;

 * Read configuration from dbconfig-common
 * You can regenerate it using: dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
 */
if (is_readable('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php')) {
    require('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php');
}

if (!empty($dbname)) {
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'signon';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'SignonSession';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL'] = 'https://phpmyadmin.example.com/console.php';
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;

    if (!empty($dbport)) {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
    }
    /* Select mysqli if your server has it */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    /* Optional: User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
    /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';

}

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'db1.example.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'SignonSession';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL'] = 'https://phpmyadmin.example.com/console.php';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';

$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you've configured a `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost']`, which is needed to tell phpMyAdmin which server to use for the central database. See also http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controlhost. I suspect once you add that line, you'll have better luck.

Comment: OK. Missed that. Now I have set controlhost as `localhost`, but still getting the same error. I assume that I do not need controluser and controlpass since I am using signon. as per [this](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controlpass) page

Comment: btw, In case it is relavant, I see these warnings also. _Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.66 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.28. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to documentation for possible issues._

Comment: Sorry guys, I was using an older version of phpmyadmin (3.3 which came with debian). I am not testing with latest version. Will update soon.

Comment: Yes. Version 4.0.1 worked. This question should be marked as invalid or deleted.